# Calling a function using variable name in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Thanks in advance.

I'm trying to call a function using a variable name. It's throwing the error

**The macro 'testfunc' cannot be found.
Resume without error**

**My Code:** I tried below 3 statements but all are throwing the same error.

```
sFuncName = "testfunc"

ExtractData = Application.Run("Sheet.xls" & sFuncName, s1, s2)

ExtractData = Application.Run(sFuncName, s1, s2)

ExtractData = CallByName("Sheet.xls", sFuncName, VbMethod, s1, s2)
```

Note that the `sFuncName` returns a value & I have 2 Excels opened at that moment, I'm trying to copy data from one Excel to other.

Please help me in achieving this.

```
Private Function ABC
  sFuncName = oMapWksht.Cells(sMapRowItr, 3).Value
  'sFuncName = "testfunc"
  ExtractData = Application.Run("Sheet.xls" & sFuncName, s1, s2)
  'ExtractData = Application.Run(sFuncName, s1, s2)
  'ExtractData = CallByName("Sheet.xls", sFuncName, VbMethod, s1, s2)
End Function
Public Function testfunc(ByVal s1 As String, ByVal s2 As String) As    Boolean
--
---
----
End Function
```

Comment: Where exactly is `testfunc` located: is it in a different workbook from the code you posted?

Comment: I have 2 workbooks open. I have all the code in Book1 and trying to copy data from Book2.  "testfunc" is another function in same workbook.

Comment: In your `VBAProject`, make sure you put your function (such as `testfunc`) into a module (under the folder `Modules` in the Project Explorer) and not as VBA code inside a worksheet or workbook (under the folder `Microsoft Excel Objects`).

Comment: why not `ExtractData  = testfunc(s1,s2)`?

Comment: Scott -- I need to dynamically call diff functions.

Private Function ABC
    sFuncName = oMapWksht.Cells(sMapRowItr, 3).Value
 'sFuncName = "testfunc"
    ExtractData = Application.Run("Sheet.xls" & sFuncName, s1, s2)
 'ExtractData = Application.Run(sFuncName, s1, s2)
 'ExtractData = CallByName("Sheet.xls", sFuncName, VbMethod, s1, s2)
End Function
Public Function testfunc(ByVal s1 As String, ByVal s2 As String) As Boolean
    --
 ---
 ----
End Function

Comment: I've just added some part of my script...where I'm getting function name (sFuncName) from a cell in workbook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the function you're calling is in the same workbook as the caller, it doesn't matter how many workbooks are opened.

If the invoked procedure doesn't have a unique name across the entire project, you need to qualify the function name with at least the name of the module though. This should get you going:

**Module1** (caller)

```
Sub DoSomething()
    Debug.Print Application.Run("Module2.Test", "Test")
End Sub
```

**Module2** (callee)

```
Public Function Test(ByVal title As String) As VbMsgBoxResult
    Test = MsgBox("Works?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, title)
End Function
```

Comment: Invoked function is unique across the project. sFuncName  returns diff values as i read the value dynamically from sheet. sFuncName  returns diff values testfunc1, testfunc2 ....

Comment: Then the problem is elsewhere, possibly in the value you're reading in the cell - are you completely totally absolutely sure what you're reading matches the name of an existing procedure? No leading/trailing whitespace?

Comment: I have checked that it clearly returns the function name in error without any leading/trailing spaces. I'm using excel 2003 wonder if that wont cause any issue.

Comment: Try the example code I gave you right here, does it work? (works here on Excel 2010)

Comment: I replaced ("Module2.Test", "Test")  to  ("sheet.xls!testfunc", "Test")   and it returned same error...macro cannot be found

Comment: yes its enabled...other functions are populating data (directly called instead of variable)

Comment: Is `testFunc` located in a standard code module (.bas)? It won't work if it's in a class module (.cls) or a workbook/worksheet's code-behind.

Comment: sorry I'm not that aware of .bas or .cls.... i just started working on VBA and i'm trying to add some features to existing code....please excuse for my ignorance

Comment: Ok that must be it then - Ctrl+R get to the project explorer, right-click and select "add module" and put your function in there.

Comment: Thanks Mat...You're correct.. I created a module and placed the function in that module and I'm able to access the function..

Comment: You should ask another question, that's a totally different issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **String** variable to hold the Sub's name.  Here is an example of a Sub in the same module as the caller:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim st As String
    st = "whatever"
    Application.Run st
End Sub

Public Sub whatever()
    MsgBox "whatever"
End Sub
```

If the caller and called subs are in different modules, the syntax may be slightly different.

**EDIT#1:**

If we want to call a Sub in a different module within the *same workbook*, the syntax would be the same.

If we want to call a Sub within *another workbook*, and both workbooks are open then the caller would look like:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim st As String
    st = "Book2.xlsm!whatever"
    Application.Run st
End Sub
```

I usually declare the called Sub `Public`, but I don't know if this is necessary.

**EDIT#2**

To use another workbook's *UDF()* in a worksheet cell, then:

[image]

where `qwerty()` is a `Public` *UDF()*

Comment: I've just added some part of my script...where I'm getting function name (sFuncName )from a cell in workbook.